# Appending an object to serialized form data

Tags: jquery, ajax

So I have an object that looks like this, lets say it's called `obj`:

```
var obj = [{
    "cella": "test1",
    "cellb": "test2 ",
    "cell3": "test3"
}]
```

Now I want to POST this along with serialized form data to a PHP controller using AJAX. The problem I'm encountering is how to actually pass the data. I have tried:

```
{
    "json object": obj
}
```

And:

```
data: "json object=" + obj + $("#form").serialize(),
```

However I'm unable to post over both the form data and object in the correct format. Should I be looking to add the form data to the object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide the object (note that it is nothing to do with JSON) to the `data` property of a `$.ajax` request along with the serialized form data using `$.param`. Try this:

```
var obj = [{
    "cella": "test1",
    "cellb": "test2 ",
    "cell3": "test3"
}]

$.ajax({
    url: 'your-php-page.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#form').serialize() + '&' + $.param(obj[0]),
    success: function(returnedData) {
        console.log('it worked');
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log('it didnt work, you can check the passed in parameter to debug');
    }
});
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eqj65uv5/)

Note that the demo shows the output of appending the parameterised object to the serialised form.

Note that for an array of objects you would need to loop over them, appending to the serialized form on each iteration, something like this:

```
function buildQuerystring() {
    var qs = $('#form').serialize();
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        qs += '&' + $.param(obj[i]);
    }
}

// in the $.ajax call:
data: buildQuerystring(),
```

Comment: if it was an array of objects how would that work? example ` [{"cella":"test2 1","cellb":"1","cellc":"1"},{"cella":"test1","cellb":"1 ","cellc":"1"}] `

Comment: You would need to loop over the array, and append the `$.param(obj[n])` string for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

before serializing form, append an input element

```
var obj = [{
  "cella": "test1",
  "cellb": "test2 ",
  "cell3": "test3"
}];

  obj.map(item => {
    $("#form").append(`<input type="hidden" name="cella" value="${item.cella}"/>`);
    $("#form").append(`<input type="hidden" name="cellb" value="${item.cellb}"/>`);
    $("#form").append(`<input type="hidden" name="cell3" value="${item.cell3}"/>`);
  })
```